# What does reduce() do without mapper() in MRJob?

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, mrjob

I am new to python and trying to build a recommendation system following the instruction http://www.yekeren.com/blog/archives/1005,

what confuses me is that :

```
def reducer3_init(self):
        self.pop = { }

        file = open(self.options.item_pop, "r")

        for line in file.readlines():
            movieid_jstr, pop_jstr = line.strip().split("\t")
            movieid = json.loads(movieid_jstr)
            pop     = json.loads(pop_jstr)

            self.pop[movieid] = pop
        file.close()

    def reducer3(self, key, values):
        yield key, sum(values) / math.sqrt(self.pop[key[0]] * self.pop[key[1]])
```

The `reduce3` has no corresponding `mapper`,how does it execute ? and what does json.load() do?
   A Lot Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://mrjob.readthedocs.org/en/latest/step.html#mrjob.step.MRStep) says:

> class mrjob.step.MRStep(**kwargs)
>
> ```
> Used by MRJob.steps. See Multi-step jobs for sample usage.
> ```
>
> Accepts the following keyword arguments. Parameters:
>
> ```
> mapper – function with same function signature as mapper(), or None for an identity mapper.
> ```

It is an idiom that map defaults to identity and reduce to flatten.